# isFullScreen manifest setting doesn't do anything

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've created a simple Teams app with a single Personal tab defined.
In the manifest there is a setting `isFullScreen: true`. My hope was that enabling this property would no longer show the Tabs bar on top of the application. However, this does not seem to be the case.

Furthermore, I don't see any change in the application, whether `isFullScreen` is set to `true` or `false`.

Does anyone know what this property actually changes? Or am I missing something else perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked this morning, and the issue is resolved.
The isFullScreen flag now works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue. We have raised a bug for this and we are working on fixing this. But we cannot give you an ETA on when this will be available.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Do you have any screenshots or additional docs on what it _should_ look like? This could prove a very useful setting towards the further development of our product.

Comment: Currently its not documented anywhere. We are working on updating the docs to add this.