# Microsoft Teams Manifest isFullScreen doesn't work

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am using the yeomen generator to create a Microsoft Teams Application with NodeJS and React. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/quickstarts/create-personal-tab-node-yeoman

I implemented the "isFullScreen" option  into the Schema, but it just doesn't work. Here my Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.7/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.7",
  "packageName": "TeamsApp",
  "id": "8af948a0-0fc1-409c-942a-9376fc2d7f46",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "isFullScreen": true,
  "showLoadingIndicator": true,
  "developer": {
    "name": "xxx GmbH",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.xxx.de",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.xxx.de/Datenschutz",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.xxx.de",
    "mpnId": "1512061"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Teams App",
    "full": "Teams App Tool "
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "xxx",
    "full": "xxx"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "icon-outline.png",
    "color": "icon-color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#004578",
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "contentUrl": "https://xxx.ngrok.io/overviewTab",
      "entityId": "TeamsApp",
      "name": "Overview",
      "scopes": ["personal"]
    }
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "*.eu.ngrok.io"
  ]
}
```

I Developed a Microsoft Teams App with SPfx before and there the option worked completely fine. I also tried using the App Studio Application where the "isFullScreen" option is displayed, but even there it does not do anything.

In a another Post from 3 Months ago they just said it should work now. [isFullScreen manifest setting doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62895000/isfullscreen-manifest-setting-doesnt-do-anything)

Answer (score 1):

"isFullScreen" works only with LoB Store Apps.

Comment: So do i understand it correctly that this feature is not supportet for the regular store applications? So only if i Implement the manifest via admin center this would work?

Comment: LoB means "line of business". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/distribute-lob-apps-to-enterprises